# Possible to share multiple actions to Timeline on a single page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

Is it possible to have multiple (unique) actions publish to Facebook's Timeline on a single page?

For instance, say I had an aggregator like reddit and I wanted to publish when a user upvoted a story. I would want each upvote to be published as a separate event ("user x upvoted story y on my_app_name").

The [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) describes how facebook uses custom 'meta' tags to retrieve information about the action. Is there any other way I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Posting without the meta tags is not possible. Why don't you create a custom site that gets the meta information via $_GET, and share this URL?